# Why is Sprite a child in Eternals?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals

In *Eternals*, this doesn't make sense to me because it just seems weird why Sprite is the only 'child' and she's talking about how she's in love with Ikaris.

Comment: Sprite isn't a child, she is only given that appearance.

Comment: I know most of the movie was one long, long info-dump of exposition, so much that there was barely any room left for plot or character development, but you had to have noticed none of them appear physically any older in 7,000 years, even if you weren't listening as to exactly *why* that is [& kudos to Paulie for not actually spoilering that in his answer.]

Comment: All the eternals are physically different ages. You could just as well ask why is Ajak the only Eternal depicted as someone in their 50s? 

A better question is why is this creature, older than humanity, going off to school at the end of the movie? That makes zero sense :)

Answer (score 9):

Sprite is not a "child" as such, she's millions of years old and merely has *the appearance* of a child.

She's known Ikaris for thousands of years and despite her physical form there is no particular reason should should *not* have feelings for him.

We are not told why this is the case within the movie although it's possible that this has been done (out of universe) to emphasise her difficulties in fitting in with human society and highlight her "sacrifice" in giving up her immortality to *be* human.

Comment: Gaiman was responsible for Sprite's physical age as a retcon. **He** [in the comics] is only 3000 years old - so apparently the movie is retconning yet again. ;)

Comment: No one wants to watch a 46yo give up their immortality. That would be a tragedy exploring the human condition instead of love.

Answer (score 2):

Just gonna lift this verbatim from [the source](https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2022/01/17/why-is-sprite-a-child-in-eternals-characters-age-explored/), since there's no way to really reword it better:

> **WHY IS SPRITE A CHILD IN ETERNALS?**
>
> Played by Lia McHugh, Sprite was designed by the maker of the Eternals
> – the Celestials – to look approximately 11 or 12 years old.
>
> Even in Marvel Comics, Sprite is the youngest looking Eternal out of
> the group of heroes – even though Sprite is depicted as a male
> character in the source material.
>
> All of the Eternals were created at the same time and made immortal,
> meaning they all carry the same age and never grow older.
>
> There is no definitive reason given in the comics as to why Sprite was
> made to look younger than the rest, but this decision does impact the
> character’s emotional drive.